# Vim remembering buffer list

Tags: vim, buffer

When I open vim (or gvim), it loads a list of buffers of files I have been working on. I want it to have an empty buffer list on startup. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: check your 'viminfo' setting

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Too many open buffers slows down Vim terribly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have the `%` value in your `'viminfo'` option; it enables restoring of the buffer list. As this is off by default, you (or your Vim distribution) must have turned that on.

`:help viminfo-%`:

> %   When included, save and restore the buffer list.  If Vim is
>         started with a file name argument, the buffer list is not
>         restored.  If Vim is started without a file name argument, the
>         buffer list is restored from the viminfo file.

Comment: Thanks, I searched through my `.vimrc` and found that enabled.